# How to send protobuffer with Jmeter to a HornetQ server

Tags: architecture, jmeter, protocol-buffers, performance-testing, hornetq

I'd like to know how could I send messages in protobuf format with Jmeter to a Queue server, in my case It's the HornetQ implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to code it using a [Protobuffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) java client and one of those 2 options:

- [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) + [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/)
- [AbstractJavaSamplerClient](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html)